# Create Pandas mask if comparing 2 columns of different names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a mask below that works if the names of the two columns in the two dataframes being compared are the same.

```
mask1 = df1[['date','ID']].isin(df2[['date','ID']]).any(axis=1)
```

Is there any way to make the same comparison if the names of the compared columns are different? Like:

```
mask2 = df1[['DATES','ids']].isin(df2[['date','ID']]).any(axis=1)
```

Comment: Does the second one not work? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do that is by getting their values (then ignoring the column names, considering the column orders instead):

```
mask2 = np.any(df1[['DATES','ids']].values == df2[['date','ID']].values, axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 0

Comment: Are you sure your dataframes are ok? It's supposed to work. Proving a small chunk of your dataframes, or example data would be good.